# Referencing Groovy project from another using Eclipse, Maven, maven-eclipse-plugin and build-helper-maven-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, groovy

I have an Eclipse Groovy project, say A,  that needs to reference/use the source code of another Eclipse Groovy project, called GenUtils. 
In the Eclipse environment one would select project A and then Properties --> Projects --> Add and check GenUtils.
This produces the following in the .classpath file of A:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
...
...
<classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/GenUtils"/>
```

where "/GenUtils" referenes a project in the workspace. And this works fine.

Now I am trying to do the same with Maven using the maven-eclipse-plugin to generate the Eclipse project files for A from the maven pom.xml.
(Using mvn eclipse:eclipse)

By researching (I am a Maven newbie) I found that Maven does not support multiple source locations by default and the recommended solution is
the build-helper-maven-plugin. Using this in my POM:

```
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>../../GenUtils</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I can give the relative path of the GenUtils project. This produces the following in the .classpath file:
    
that is, the project sources are indeed referenced with an absolute path! Not ideal but would do for the moment.

The problem is that Eclipse does not accept this and gives the errors: ": is an invalid character in path 'C:/_*SDE/Tools/ArtopBasedTools/GenUtils'." (Error Log), 
"Project A us missing required source folder: 'C:/*_SDE/Tools/ArtopBasedTools/GenUtils'" (Problems wndow). This is probably due to the fact that Eclipse expects
to reference other workspace projects not arbitrary directories. It expects in the .classpath file a path="/GenUtils" entry instead of the full absolute path.

So the question is: 
Is there a way to specify this in build-helper-maven-plugin?

More generaly:
Is this the correct approach to make accesible a Groovy Eclipse project from another using Maven? Or is there another recommended solution?

Comment: There is no need (as far as I understand from your post) to add source for module `A` as it should be binary dependent on module `GenUtils`, so the `add-source` goal is redundant

Comment: @orid: (Hopefully I do not misunderstand your statement). My intention is to make the functionality of GenUtils available to project A. Since both projects are Groovy code/scripts there is no generated .jar to reference. In the way our Eclipse projects are constructed is that A just references project GenUtils in Eclipse (please refer to the first lines in my question) and this way A can call all functionality of GenUtils.

Comment: @orid: In other words, technically speaking, A is not "binary" dependent to GenUtils since it is not depending on a .jar or even a collection of .class files of GenUtils. It is "source/script" dependent to GenUtils. I am not so sure that this is supported by the dependency mechanism of Maven. However the inclusion of multiple source origins IS indeed supported with the help of build-helper-maven-plugin. Unfortunately I have not managed to make it produce an Eclipse compatible .classpath from that.